# Difference between Category and Class Extension?

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between a Category and a Class Extension. I believe both are used to add custom methods in existing classes. Can someone throw light on this? Examplification with code will be really appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1

Comment: Akusete, page cannot be found.

Comment: clearly illustrated here, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-succinctly-categories-and-extensions--mobile-22016

Answer (score 107, accepted):

A category is a way to add methods to existing classes.  They usually reside in files called "Class+CategoryName.h", like "NSView+CustomAdditions.h" (and .m, of course).

A class extension is a category, except for 2 main differences:

1. The category has no name.  It is declared like this:

   ```
   @interface SomeClass ()

   - (void) anAdditionalMethod;


   @end
   ```
2. The implementation of the extension *must* be in the main @implementation block of the file.

It's quite common to see a class extension at the top of a .m file declaring more methods on the class, that are then implemented below in the main @implementation section of the class.  This is a way to declare "pseudo-private" methods (pseudo-private in that they're not really private, just not externally exposed).

Comment: In Class-Extensiosn you're able to overwrite properties from a (public) read-only property to be internally readwrite.

And since LLVM 1.5 you're able to do even more: you can now declare instance variables in a class extension so they are gone from the regular interface.

Comment: Why add a class extension when you could just implement those methods and properties strait into the class? Seems a little redundant to me.

Comment: @user1721803 As Dave suggested you might want to keep few properties/methods unexposed. This is when extensions are used. Consider a view, you could hook up all your IBOutlets and IBActions in extension and expose methods which allows to initialize/update Outlets and Actions could be delegated back.

Comment: @MaxSeelemann can you please demo how to make "a (public) read-only property to be internally readwrite" by a short script? Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33942484/3798182) states extension in "Class+CategoryName.swift" file, is it correct ??

Comment: @Dave DeLong [Apple Documentation on Category](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html) states "The declaration of a category interface looks very much like a class interface declaration—except that the **category name is listed within parentheses** after the class name and the superclass isn’t mentioned"

Comment: @Rishi That's talking about a category. The question was asking about a class extension, not a category. A class extension does not have a name.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Sir your 1st point says **"The category has no name. It is declared like this:"** But Category has a name and it is not declared like this, Am i missing something sir ?
I am totally confused

Comment: @Rishi it's saying that a class extension is like a category, except that the "category" for a class extension "has no name"

Comment: @DaveDeLong Unlike Objective-C categories, Swift extensions do not have names.

Comment: @Rishi what does Swift have to do with anything? There's no Swift anywhere in this question and answer, because it's from 2010, about 4 *years* before Swift was released.

Comment: @DaveDeLong When you say "category" for a class extension "has no name". you are referring to extension?, because Apple Documents says **"Unlike Objective-C categories, Swift extensions do not have names"**. Which means Objective-C categories have names. yes the question was asked in 2010, But unfortunately I have to give interviews in 2017. I am sorry for asking it again. Kindly refer me a place, book or website where i can clear my basics of Objective-C. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 49):

1. **Category**

=> In Objective C, when you want to add some more   functionality to a class without inheritance, you simply use category for it.

=> it comes with its own **.h** and **.m** file

=> `Category` uses to add new method not properties.

2. **Class Extension**

```
-> In Objective C, when you want to make behaviour of some property private you use class extension.

-> it comes with **.h** file only.

-> mainly for properties.
```

> Note: when we add a new file and select a option of objective c
> category shows category and "category on" not "subclass of" so it
> shows like

```
@interface className (categoryName)
@end
```

-You will get two file **.h** and **.m**  with file name as (**className+categoryName.h** and **className+categoryName.m**)

and in extension case you will get

```
@interface className()
@end
```

-You will get only one file with name as **className_extensionName.h**

- In category you don't own the class but in extension you are.

Comment: @Prasanna: class extension comes with .m file only and not in .h

Comment: class extension comes with a .h file only and not a .m

Answer (score 37):

1. Category is a way to add methods to a class whether or not source code is available, meaning you can add category to foundation classes like `NSString` and also to your own custom classes.

   Extension can only be added to the classes whose source code is available because compiler compiles the source code and extension at the same time.
2. We can add extra instance variables and properties in class extension but not in category.
3. Any variable and method inside the extension is not even accessible to inherited classes.
4. Category and extension both are basically made to handle large code base, but category is a way to extend class API in multiple source files while extension is a way to add required methods outside the main interface file.
5. Use category when you have to break your same class code into different source files according to different functionalities, and extension when you just need to add some required methods to existing class outside the main interface file.
   Also, when you need to modify a publicly declared instance variable in a class, for example,
   readonly to readwrite, you can re-declare it in extension.

Comment: I read 5 similar questions with many answers, and this is the best. Thank you!

Comment: You can add properties in category as well. See @Pebby answer.

Comment: Why - Any variable and method inside the extension is not even accessible to inherited classes.? Can elaborate this?

Answer (score 7):

**Extension**: To make methods private and to add properties of our own custom class, not of Apple class.

**Category**: To add more methods in existing class not the property, it can be used for both custom class and Apple class like `NSString`.

Comment: Simple and elegant. Keep it up

Answer (score 3):

We can also have properties Using set associated property in category class.

```
@interface SomeClass (Private)

@property (nonatomic, assign) id newProperty;

@end

NSString * const kNewPropertyKey = @"kNewPropertyKey";

@implementation SomeClass (Private)

@dynamic newProperty;

- (void)setNewProperty:(id)aObject
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kNewPropertyKey, aObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (id)newProperty
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kNewPropertyKey);
}

@end
```

Refer : http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/ios-development/how-to-add-a-property-via-class-category/

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface SomeClass ()


- (void) anAdditionalMethod;


@end
```

I think it is not the way to declare Category.
Category must have a name

```
@interface SomeClass (XYZ)


- (void) anAdditionalMethod;


@end
```

for example

```
@interface NSMutableArray (NSMutableArrayCreation)

+ (id)arrayWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems;
- (id)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems;

@end
```

Declared for NSMutableArray by Apple

Comment: This is how you declare and extension, not a category -> @interface SomeClass ()

Answer (score 0):

Categories

Categories are used when you are creating file containing large number of methods.So they provide you with the facility to break a single class into different modules.Also if any changes are made to the categories the compiler does not waste time to compile the entire project.Categories are not able to add new variable or properties and look upto their parent class .You can override a method in a category but it isnt a good idea because the method cannot further be overridden.Also the flow can be effected because all categories have the same hierarchial level and hence two categories belonging to same parent class may exist at run time.Also protected methods can be created using categories

Extensions

Extensions enable you to override the property or add new property to the existing parent class.Syntatically same to categories they do not have name and are represented as @interface class()
No .m file is present and method declared in extension have to be implemented in @implementation of parent file

More help at [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-succinctly-categories-and-extensions--mobile-22016) link

Answer (score 0):

ios extension similiar to c#,java abstract class or interface

ios category similiar to c#,java class extension

Comment: your answer just like "cat is similar to tiger, answering a blind man". Lol

Comment: it is not actually.
It is the most direct and fast explanation if you know c# or java.

Comment: Not very descriptive at all, and barely answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding :

Extensions are usually used to add extra features to our own "**custom class**". We can add private methods or properties extending the class interface which can be used within the implementation of the class.

Extensions are to be written within the same file as the class. Hence you cannot write extensions for pre defined types like String, Float, etc.

On the other hand Categories can be used to add extra methods to a pre existing classes. Example we can create our own methods by extending String class. Note that we **cannot create extra properties** in the categories. Also main advantage of categories is we can write the categories in any other file, outside the file where your class exits.

Also while creating categories you are supposed to give a name for it within the brackets. 
But for extension no name is required. Hence some times they are also called anonymous categories.

Comment: You are little off track.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper We can write the extension for predefined types.

Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33942484/2060508

Answer (score 0):

### Categories and Extensions

A category allows you to add methods to an existing class—even to one for which you do not have the source. Categories are a powerful feature that allows you to extend the functionality of existing classes without subclassing. Using categories, you can also distribute the implementation of your own classes among several files. Class extensions are similar, but allow additional required APIs to be declared for a class in locations other than within the primary class *@interface* block.

### Adding Methods to Classes

You can add methods to a class by declaring them in an interface file under a category name and defining them in an implementation file under the same name. The category name indicates that the methods are additions to a class declared elsewhere, not a new class. You cannot, however, use a category to add additional instance variables to a class.

The methods the category adds become part of the class type. For example, methods added to the *NSArray* class in a category are included as methods the compiler expects an *NSArray* instance to have in its repertoire. Methods added to the *NSArray* class in a subclass, however, are not included in the *NSArray* type. (This matters only for statically typed objects because static typing is the only way the compiler can know an object’s class.)

Category methods can do anything that methods defined in the class proper can do. At runtime, there’s no difference. The methods the category adds to the class are inherited by all the class’s subclasses, just like other methods.

The declaration of a category interface looks very much like a class interface declaration—except the category name is listed within parentheses after the class name and the superclass isn’t mentioned. Unless its methods don’t access any instance variables of the class, the category must import the interface file for the class it extends:

```
#import "ClassName.h"
 
@interface ClassName ( CategoryName )
// method declarations
@end
```

Note that a category can’t declare additional instance variables for the class; it includes only methods. However, all instance variables within the scope of the class are also within the scope of the category. That includes all instance variables declared by the class, even ones declared *@private*.

There’s no limit to the number of categories that you can add to a class, but each category name must be different, and each should declare and define a different set of methods.

### Extensions

Class extensions are like anonymous categories, except that the methods they declare must be implemented in the main *@implementation* block for the corresponding class. Using the Clang/LLVM 2.0 compiler, you can also declare properties and instance variables in a class extension.

A common use for class extensions is to redeclare property that is publicly declared as read-only privately as readwrite:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (retain, readonly) float value;
@end
 
// Private extension, typically hidden in the main implementation file.
@interface MyClass ()
@property (retain, readwrite) float value;
@end

// Notice that (in contrast to a category) no name is given in the parentheses in the second @interface block.
```

It is also generally common for a class to have a publicly declared API and to then have additional methods declared privately for use solely by the class or the framework within which the class resides. Class extensions allow you to declare additional required methods for a class in locations other than within the primary class *@interface* block, as illustrated in the following example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (float)value;
@end
 
 
@interface MyClass () {
    float value;
}
- (void)setValue:(float)newValue;
@end
 
@implementation MyClass
 
- (float)value {
    return value;
}
 
- (void)setValue:(float)newValue {
    value = newValue;
}
 
@end
```

The implementation of the *setValue:* method must appear within the main *@implementation* block for the class (you cannot implement it in a category). If this is not the case, the compiler emits a warning that it cannot find a method definition for *setValue:*.
For official documentation follow this link: [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html)